# Why does ES6 use $ AND braces to denote template literals?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I was just reading up on some of the new features of ES6 and I like a lot of the new additions, however I am confused why template literals require both a `$` and `{}` to denote the variable?  It seems excessive to the point that it defeats the purpose of them to begin with (to save space and improve readability).  My only guess is they were drawing inspiration from php and wanted to be different to distinguish the two.  But with the curly braces added, you almost end up saving no more space than if you just construct a string the old way!

Comment: Because `$a + b` doesn't work. _"to denote the variable"_ Expressions, not variables. _"you almost end up saving no more space"_ Saving space is not the point.

Comment: @zeroflagL I think they mean though why not simply `{a + b}` seeing as the literal is denoted by backticks already

Comment: @RGraham Good point. Though literal `{}` might be used more often than literal `${}`.

Answer (score 2):

As it's noted in the [initial proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:quasis):

> Since we’re choosing syntax to reduce the learning curve, we chose `${...}` since it is used to allow arbitrary embedded expressions in PHP and JQuery templates. We also include the abbreviated form (`$ident`) to be compatible with Bash, Perl, PHP, Ruby, etc.
>
> We decided against sprintf style formatting, since, although widely understood, it does not allow many DSL applications, and imposes an O(n) cognitive load (2).
>
> Alternatives include:
> Bash: `$(...)`
> Ruby: `#{...}`

As we can see of today though, the short syntax with just `$expr` was not accepted (perhaps because initially it was focused on using with variable names, not arbitrary expressions).

Comment: True, the braces allow arbitrary expressions which is nice.  A shorthand `$var` would have been a nice inclusion though.